# How to monitor oracle DB updates?

Tags: php, oracle, architecture, process-monitoring

I want to notify website visitors about oracle table updates in current time. How to do this?

Comment: This is way too broad a question at the moment. Short of answering with "you will have to spam your database constantly checking for updates via one method or another..." you will need to provide a heck of a lot more in your question. What are you thinking, when you say current time, do you mean true real time, or within 5 or so minutes of an update. C'mon, give your potential answers *something* to work with.

Comment: I mean true real time. Call centre operators must know who calls in current time. Every call immediately writes to DB. Website works on php with oracle DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the database do its work (i.e. hold and manage the data) and have the notification done by the application, that handles the incoming call.